# Handlebars helper does not work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have created an Handlebars helper like the following.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("format_currency", function(value, currency){

    var symbol = "";
    if(currency === "EUR") symbol = "&#8364;";
    else if ... // other code here

    return value + " " + symbol;
});
```

that I use in the following manner

```
{{format_currency amount currency}}
```

When I run the application application, the value field has the correct value (say 1.5) while the currency in an object that hash an hash property inside. Why? Here I would expect the currency I passed in (say "EUR").

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what "an object that hash an hash property inside" means but I see one problem with your helper (or the way you're using it) that will make it produce odd results.

When you use `{{...}}`, Handlebars is expecting plain text so it will HTML encode it. So if your `symbol` ends up being `"&#8364;"`, the ampersand will be HTML encoded and you'll get `&amp;#8364;` added to your template rather than the Unicode entity for the Euro symbol.

There are a few ways around this problem.

## Triple Stashes

One way to fix the encoding problem use triple-stashes in your template to disable the HTML encoding:

```
{{{format_currency amount currency}}}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Q4FcR/

## Plain Unicode

Another way is to abandon the entities in favor of a raw Unicode Euro character:

```
if(currency === "EUR")
    symbol = '€';
```

Then you don't have to worry about double-stashes or triple-stashes or HTML encoding or ...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Mfuk7/

## SafeString

Another way is to return a [`Handlebars.SafeString`](http://handlebarsjs.com) instead of a `String`:

> Handlebars will not escape a `Handlebars.SafeString`. If you write a helper that generates its own HTML, you will usually want to return a `new Handlebars.SafeString(result)`.

So you'd have this in your helper:

```
return new Handlebars.SafeString(value + " " + symbol);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AZtCE/

Comment: Thanks. +1 your support. With that sentence I mean that the currency value is not read correctly. While the value is exported correctly, the currency is not exported anywhere. Handlebars, as the second parameter, creates the empty object with an hash inside. Any advice?

Comment: Have you done a `console.log(arguments)` in your helper to see what is really being passed? Are you using an old version of Handlebars? What are you doing differently than my fiddles?